# Authentication-Authorization issue when dealing with WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm re-developing an app as a web app (the "previous" iteration was in VB6) to run on **azure**. One requirement is that we **only use facebook/google authentication (OAuth 2.0)**. Another business requirement lead me to break my project into the following schema:

- 1 Project for the WebAPI 2.0
- 1 Project for Controllers
- 1 for Data Access (typical layer pattern)
- **N** Projects for MVC 5 front-end

The idea is that the MVC projects will only consume the WebAPI via javascript/json! The N MVC projects will contain just the `GET` implementation for the pages. No models or others actions (post for example). In other words **the MVC projects are completally disconnectd from the other projects and should have no intelligence what-so-ever!**

This is the selected way because of (bitchy clients and) limited time constraints.
Anyway, as you can notice the "core" (WebAPI + controllers + DA) is shared. The core is in fact a multi-tenant service. **(but remember the disconnected facet!)**

My problem here is: How do I handle Authorization? What/how should treat the passing of the claims between the MVC projects and the WebAPI? Im lost here. After some thought, I came to the conclusion that I need to make the WebAPI project act as a proxy here, something like:

- Random users lands on `www.myClientWebsite.com/Register`
- Chooses a login provider
- The MVC project redirects the user signaling facebook to return to `www.myWebAPI.com/Register`
- I intercept the claim and redirect the user to the original `www.myClientWebsite.com/LoginComplete` or something...

Am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use OAuth 2 for authentication and authorization purpose in this scenario. Yes, you should be making the authentication at the MVC level and then use tokens to keep the security intact for rest calls.

Here your MVC application should get a Bearer token from the identity provider like google and then hide it some where on the form. Then for every jquery request you make to web api, you have to send this bearer token in the request.

**[Update]**
This is considered kind of hack and I do not encourage it. And this works only if both the systems are in same domain.
**[\Update]**

If both MVC and Web API are on different domains, then you can think of using Azure ACS Service Identity to build the trust between domains. Then pass the bearer token of User claims in the payload of the request.

**[Update]**
This is much more better way to handle this but must be accompanied with proper token revocation and https security.
**[\Update]**

Comment: could you elaborate more on the Token part? like how should i do it with a bit more details?!?

Comment: It can be a custom implementation, say frontend is getting authenticated against google. So frontend got Google user claims because of user login. Now frontend and backend are configured for Azure ACS Service identity, so that frontend gets a ACS token from ACS end point and using that token along with claims (as request payload) makes a request to backend service. Backend service using a delegating handler checks for the ACS token validity. If valid accept the request and its associated payload. Or else throw an error.